# ng-select in Angular v9 app [appendTo]="'body'" doesn't work

Tags: node-modules, angular9

The problem is that my dropdown from ng-select "cut" and hidden behind as-split.
[appendTo]="'body'" seems to be not working.

*there is style for position: relative

you can see in source that the <ng-dropdown-panel..> not append to body.
I tried also adding: appendTo="body", and tried to append to a different container.
I also tried with z-index or to remove my css.

It's not working.
any idea why it can be?
is there a known bug?

Thanks.